# Tornado testing with timeout response

Tags: django, tornado

I have two tornado running on 1 machine and from time to time they freeze.

I'm coding a script to test the response of them or the timeout but with no luck.
I tried `python3 -m tornado.testing tornado.test.web_test` which works fine and give me some test results, so I was wondering if there is a way to make a ping to a tornado and get a response maybe from a .py file or directly from console.

Also a simple ping will be valid.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: To get a response from Tornado, make an HTTP request to your handlers. You can use `urllib` or `requests` package to make http requests from a python file. Or you can use `wget` or `curl` to make request from console.

Comment: @xyres i tried this with r = urllib.request.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8000',timeout=5).read() but i always get a 400 bad request

Comment: It's hard to tell where the problem may be without seeing your code.